# how to measure performance data for flash based games?

Tags: testing, flash, profiling, performance-testing

I am facing some issues in performing perf testing of Flash based games.

- How can I perform performance  testing for a flash game?
- Would you recommend any automated tool for testing a flash game?

I need to capture the performance data for flash games for 1 client session. In Chrome I am unable to inspect the dev tool to look into performance .

I need to capture initial load, splash screen, fps, cpu usage, gpu etc

Comment: _`I need to capture initial load, splash screen, fps, cpu usage, gpu etc`_ Doesn't make sense. What is `capture the gpu`? No one can help you like this. Try also Adobe Scout for perfomance tests on your SWF files like CPU & memory usage etc. I don't thinkanyone recreated Chrome's Dev Tools just for analyzing SWF files.

Comment: thanks for the response  i need to capture perf data  of flash based game applications  ..initial load to user actions and spalsh screen am analyzing ..am using profiler only(adobe scoutt).suggest me to approach